# How to share folders/drives/files on a Windows 7 with a Mac

Tags: windows-7, macos, file-sharing

Both our machines (OSX and Win7) are connected to a WiFi router.

How can I share files on my Windows 7 machine with the Mac which has Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Share a folder on the Windows machine then use "**`Connect to server`**" on the Mac with  an address of:

> `smb://NameOfWindowsMachine/NameOfWindowsShare`

Put anything you want to access from both machines into that `folder/share`